# How to set ag-grid drop-down values programmatically (in JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, ag-grid

I have this cell in my grid.

```
        {
            headerName: "Type",
            field: "Type",
            getQuickFilterText: () => '',
            editable: true,
            width: 250,
            cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
            cellEditorPopup: true,
            cellRenderer: TypeCellRenderer,
            keyCreator: (params) => {
                return params.value.vcTypeName;
            },
            cellEditorParams: {
                cellRenderer: TypeCellRenderer,
            },
        },
```

How do I set the drop-down values of this cell from my function setValues()?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 - more customizable:**
You can use the `cellEditorSelector`. This selects which dropdown values you want. In your column def's you specify:

```
{ headerName: "Item Type", field: "itemType", cellEditorSelector: this.itemTypeSelector},
```

Then, when defining what actual dropdown you programmatically want to select, you define it in the method used for the `cellEditorSelector`, which, in our case, is `itemTypeSelector`:

```
itemTypeSelector = (params) => {
if (params.data.itemType == 'foo') {
  return {
    component: 'agSelectCellEditor',
    params: {
      values: ['1', '2', '3'],
    },
    popup: true
  };
}
else if (params.data.itemType == 'bar') {
  return {
    component: 'agSelectCellEditor',
    params: {
      values: ['4', '5', '6'],
    },
    popup: true
  };
}
```

}

Note that the component used is `agSelectCellEditor` but can be any other including the rich cell select editor.

**Option 2 - less customizable:**

```
cellEditor : 'agSelectCellEditor';
cellEditorParams: function(params) {
var selectedCountry = params.data.country;
if (selectedCountry==='Ireland') {
    return {
        values: ['Dublin','Cork','Galway']
    };
} else {
    return {
        values: ['New York','Los Angeles','Chicago','Houston']
    };
}
```

}